# Nginx Proxy On Custom Port

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, proxy, port

I have a node process listening on port 11180, and would like to redirect all request from https:example.com:11179 to it. How can I accomplish this with nginx ?

I cannot use port 443, because it is forwarding to a different process. However I do have a certificate for the domain example.com

I have tried using this configuration

```
server {
  listen 11179 ssl
  location / {
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:11180
      ...
  }
}
```

but the site just keeps loading, however the same configuration works if i listen on port 443

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl
  location / {
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:11180
      ...
  }
}
```

Thanks a bunch for your help

Comment: Can you list a full Nginx config ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a firewall problem :P